# Tag auto-complete no longer works on question edit for main site

Tags: bug, status-completed

I've edited a couple of questions today on the main Webmasters site for re-tagging, and the field is no longer providing the suggestions drop-down. As a quick test to make sure I wasn't expecting something that never happened, I tried over on the main SO site, and it does work over there.

This is edit-only, as far as I can tell. The suggestions drop-down *does* appear when authoring a new question.

**EDIT**
Didn't think to check the console previously, for some reason. Firefox 4 reports:

```
Error: bindTagFilterAutoComplete is not defined Source File: [question URL] Line: 2
```

Comment: Can you try if it works now, please?

Comment: @balpha Working now. Thanks.

Comment: Great, thanks for testing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect a timing issue between the loading and execution of JavaScript files. We've seen issues like this previously; they are hard to reproduce reliably across machines.

In addition, this particular autocomplete issue would only appear for non-moderators between 2000 and 2999 reputation (you fall into these boundaries on Webmasters, as does another user on Super User who [reported the same issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98356/tag-suggestions-do-not-appear-while-inline-editing)).

So while this is indeed [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro), it's plausible; we'll have a look at trying to avoid these timing issues.

**Update:** We've made a change to how the JavaScript is loaded, and since both you and the other user report it's working now, I guess my suspicion was right.

Comment: That's...highly specific. Making it precisely the kind of bug I tend to wind up running into. Now to go troll for some rep points so it stops *grin*

Comment: That's the spirit!